# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Asp.NetCore.Http.FormFile' to type 'System.IO.Stream' in Asp.NetCore MVC web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-blob-storage

I am a newbie to Asp.netCore as well as Microsoft Azure. Recently, I am trying to integrate ASP.net Core MVC web app with blob storage.

In the application I upload an file (image) to the azure blob storage, and the URL of the uploaded file is stored in the Microsoft SQL database. The database is connected to the application perfectly and it is working fine too.
I have created an Azure blob storage and I have already created containers and have manually uploaded files to the blob storage. Blob storage also working perfect.

**This is the controller class:** (I have put the image uploading controllers in the 'HomeController' for the testing purposes

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebAppMVC.Data;
using WebAppMVC.Models;
using WebAppMVC.Utilities;

namespace WebAppMVC.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<WebAppMVCUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,UserManager<WebAppMVCUser> userManager)
    {
        _logger = logger;

        /* newly added */
        _userManager = userManager;
        utility = new BlobUtility(accountName, accountKey);
        db = new WebAppMVC_DBContext();
        /* newly added */
    }

    /* newly added */
    BlobUtility utility;
    WebAppMVC_DBContext db;
    string accountName = "_my_Storage_Name";
    string accountKey = "My_storage_account_key";
    /* newly added */

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        /* newly added */
        string loggedInUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
        List<UserMedium> userMedia = (from a in db.UserMedia where a.UserId.ToString() == loggedInUserId select a).ToList();
        ViewBag.PhotoCount = userMedia.Count;
        return View(userMedia);
        /* newly added */
    }

    /* newly added */
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult DeleteImage(int id)
    {
        UserMedium userImage = db.UserMedia.Find(id);
        db.UserMedia.Remove(userImage);
        db.SaveChanges();
        string BlobNameToDelete = userImage.ImageUrl.Split('/').Last();
        utility.DeleteBlob(BlobNameToDelete, "profilepics");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadImage(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            string ContainerName = "profilepics"; // container name. 
            //file = Request.File["file"];
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            Stream imageStream = file.OpenReadStream();
            var result = utility.UploadBlob(fileName, ContainerName, (Stream)file);
            if (result != null)
            {
                string loggedInUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
                UserMedium usermedium = new UserMedium();
                usermedium.MediaId = new Random().Next();
                try
                { 
                    usermedium.UserId = Int32.Parse(loggedInUserId);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Unable to parse '{loggedInUserId}'");
                }
                usermedium.ImageUrl = result.Uri.ToString();
                db.UserMedia.Add(usermedium);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    /* newly added */

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Media()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult InformationPortal()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
}
```

This is the **View** Index.cshtml code: (I am uploading the file from the Index.cshtml) [Uploading-Image-from-the-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXMLf.png)

```
@model IEnumerable<WebAppMVC.Models.UserMedium>
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <div class="panel panel-warning">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Upload and save your photo</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <input type="file" name="file" />
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning form-control" value="Save Photo" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

</div>

<br />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="alert alert-warning">You have @ViewBag.PhotoCount Photos </div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">

            <a class="thumbnail" href="@item.ImageUrl">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="@item.ImageUrl" style="height: 300px;width:100%;" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteImage", "Home",new { id = item.MediaId })" class="btn btn-default btn-block">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>

        </div>
    }

</div>
```

But when I run the app, after uploading the file(jpg image) I am getting the following exception:
This exception comes and application also put into the break mode.

**Exception:** [Click-here-to-see-the-exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93TCK.png)

As depicted in the picture, the application is put into the break mode and that exception is thrown at the line **74** of HomeController (The controller I used to control the file upload).

Following is the detailed description of the exception: [exception-details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61aYt.png)

And when I step forward, I am getting this error message on the browser: [Exception-error-on-browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUDyO.png)

I do not understand the error and **Does anybody know how to solve this issue?**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function to convert IFormFile to Stream.

```
    public static async Task<Stream> GetStream(this IFormFile formFile)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
IFormFile file;
byte[]? image = Array.Empty<byte>();

if (file != null)
{
    await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    await file!.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    image = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```